# Assert in afxwin1.inl on line 21 when creating and testing a custom MFC CEdit in VS2012 unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mfc, assert

My boss has a custom `CEdit` class called `CInPlaceEdit` and we're currently testing this class in Visual Studio 2012 with a unit test project. Basically we create the `CEdit` class in the unit test like this:

```
CDialog *dlg = new CDialog();
dlg->Create(IDD_EDIT_STRING);
CWnd *pListCtrl = dlg;

auto pParent = pListCtrl->GetParent();


auto editSpLat = new CInPlaceEdit(-1, i, pszBlank, GetEditTemplates()->m_pEdtSpLat, (void*)&m_pSP, pListCtrl, IPE_CTRL | IPE_PTRTOPTR_VAR | IPE_RIGHT_JUSTIFY, ids);
editSpLat->Create(dwStyle, CRect(0, 0, 1, 1), pListCtrl, IDC_INPLACEEDIT + i);
```

The assert in afxwin1.inl on line 21 is thrown during the call to Create( ... ); The assert in the file afxwin1.inl is `ASSERT(afxCurrentInstanceHandle != NULL)`. Is there a way I can make my unit tests get past this?

Comment: What is your unit test setup? Are your tests implemented in a .dll? How are the tests hosted? Is the host application an MFC application?

Comment: Yeah all our unit tests are implemented in DLLs and the application being tested is an MFC app. What do you mean how the tests are hosted?

Comment: A .dll cannot be executed by itself, you need to provide an environment that *hosts* the .dll. With your unit tests being implemented as .dll's you need to make sure to manage MFC's state properly (see [MFC Module State Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft1t4bbc.aspx) for details).

Comment: Seems like some static/dynamic linkage issue, but i might be incorrect. Take a look at this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ef4b51dc-4641-4e38-813e-c893f84dd399/why-afxgetresourcehandle-causes-asserts?forum=vclanguage

Answer (score -1):

Character set mismatch is one possibility will cause this issue.

`mfc dll` is using UNICODE.

Make sure `"IDD_EDIT_STRING"` is using unicode but not `ANSI`.

Maybe try to use `No Set` in Character set

(Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set)

Comment: Hey there, can you add more info about this? I mean more information would help everyone understand this better.